# Unable to over-ride "save" options while invoking firefox from selenium-python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Below is the code, I'm using to invoke firefox to download an xlsx file from a website.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options=webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
dest_dir = "myDir"

print (options.preferences)
#options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
#options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir",True)
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir",dest_dir)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/xlsx/xls")
print (options.preferences)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Even with those options, every time I invoke firefox, it requests below questions.

[image]

**EDIT:** After changing
`options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/xlsx/xls")`
to
`options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")`
issue is resolved. So, I was providing the wrong MIME type for an xlsx file. Referred to [What is a correct MIME type for .docx, .pptx, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc) for getting the correct type.

Thanks a lot @cruisepandey and @djmonki for your help

Comment: as per @cruisepandey solution below, you need to comma separate your mime types to `options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/xlsx, application/xls")`

Comment: @djmonki, Yes that is a mistake. But fixing that alone doesnt solve the problem

Comment: @cruisepandey also has the following: `options.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)`

Comment: @djmonki, using commas for separation, and passing the correct MIME type to "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" solved the problem for me.

Comment: well done getting it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing

```
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/xlsx/xls")
```

to

```
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

issue is resolved. So, I was providing the wrong MIME type for an xlsx file. Referred to [What is a correct MIME type for .docx, .pptx, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc) for getting the correct type.

Thanks a lot @cruisepandey and @djmonki for your help

Answer (score 1):

I generally invokes with these many preferences in my project, and they work seamlessly.

**Code :**

```
options.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream");
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False);
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True);
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True);
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False);
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False);
options.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True);
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\userid\\Desktop\\Automation")
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, it is useful for me. I've updated my question with the actual fix.